# giving me MySql Syntax error?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm a beginner in JDBC and i'm trying to insert a record into table which is as i created `raja`:

So here is my program:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class raj{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:9999/raj1", "root", "1234"
            );
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

            String sql="insert into raja"+
                    "values(1, 'Rajendra Arora', 22)";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            sql="insert into raja"+
                    "values(2, 'Reena arora', 40)";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            sql="insert into raja"+
                    "values(3, 'Manohar lal arora', 45)";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            sql="insert into raja"+
                    "values(4, 'Suman and sudha arora', 20)";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            System.out.println("table records inserted succesfully....");

        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

But during execution that's showing errors as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7539 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Users\Raj Arora\IdeaProjects\untitled\out\production\untitled;C:\Users\Raj Arora\.IntelliJIdea13\config\jdbc-drivers\mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain raj
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1, 'Rajendra Arora', 22)' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2828)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1842)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1764)
    at raj.main(raj.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Printing queries before execution avoids mistakes

Comment: Yup, that makes the developer's identity... :) lol..

Comment: What the down-voters are not telling you is you forgot to put a `space` in between your table name and the `values` keyword. Failing the first time but you did this every time.

Answer (score 3):

never forgett the spaces:

```
String sql="insert into raja(col1,col2,col3) "+
                    "values(1, 'Rajendra Arora', 22)";
```

Comment: And he/she should specify the ciolumn names as well.

Answer (score 0):

Review your SQL Request ! :

`sql="insert into raja"+" values(3, 'Manohar lal arora', 45)";`

Add a space !

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a "white space" between "raja" and "values".

Also, best way to debug these issues, is to print the final sql in console and use that in any database editor.

Answer (score 0):

in your question you mention your sql like

```
String sql="insert into raja"+
                "values(1, 'Rajendra Arora', 22)";
```

but in

```
 raja"+ "values
```

is make **rajavalues.**

it must be **raja values**

so make it as

```
String sql="insert into raja "+
                "values(1, 'Rajendra Arora', 22)";
```